# How does this code works ? ( multiset sorting )

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

```
struct compare{
    bool operator() ( const string& a , const string& b ) const{
        return a.size() < b.size ();
    }
};


multiset<string , compare> stg;
```

I was solving a question and i want to sort the multiset according to string length . I searched for it in internet and got this structure . It worked for me.. But i want to know how this works...

I am just confused with this line of code .Till this point i thought that stuctures can only contain variables , not functions ..
is it something like overloading in classes .

```
 bool operator() ( const string& a , const string& b ) const{
```

Comment: Classes that overload `operator()` are called [functors or functions objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional). A function object is any object for which the function call operator is defined. Thus, an object of type `compare` (e.g., `compare foo;`) can be called in code as `foo()` and the body of `operator()` will be executed. I suggest reading a C++ book.

Comment: A `struct` and a `class` are the same thing; the only difference is that members of a `struct` are public by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structs in C++ can contain code, but it's generally a bad idea because you don't get the same level of encapsulation that you do with classes.

However, structs in C are just structures and can't contain code.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a1hcx0y.aspx